# Xamarin Forms - How to get camera stream and play with it?

Tags: camera, stream, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Since a while, but without success, I'm trying to achieve a cross-platform solution that makes me able to use a custom camera with custom functionalities. However, no one on the internet seems to get it done over each platform (Often, only Android & iOS are implemented, but no UWP) and I still don't understand why...

I've been searching for the past months how to make something, like a service, a dependency service like, from which you can get the stream/frames of the camera. Once you get it, be able to put it into an `Xamarin.Forms.Image`.

The principle of this conception would allow developers to implement functions, inside of the dependency service, such as taking video or taking pictures from the native stream camera.

You could say "But you can already use NuGet as `Xam.Plugin.Media` from James Montemagno.". Yes, but with his package, you call the native built-in camera so you can't implement your own design or your own functionalities..

So my question is: "Does someone has any tips or any project that can help to realize this project/idea?". If I can make it work, then I will create a project on my public [GitHub](https://github.com/Emixam23/XamarinByEmixam23), in order to help future people who would like to realize it.

Thank for any help

**PS: There is some results about some researches I made:** https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/284359/#Comment_284359

Answer (score 2):

This article looks to be similar to what you are after:

[Full Page Camera in Xamarin](http://thatcsharpguy.com/post/full-camera-page.1/)

It derives a camera page from ContentPage then creates platform specific custom renderers based on PageRenderer.

Bonus - there is [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/ThatCSharpGuy/Forms-FullCameraPage)

Comment: Ok I'll take a look at it tonight, thank you, I'll come back to you !

Comment: Link is dead. Please don't link to websites without writing down the solution here.